# Gulp sourcemap with less/concat/autoprefixer/minifycss?

Tags: less, concatenation, gulp, source-maps, autoprefixer

Is it possible to generate a sourcemap with all these transformations?

```
gulp.task('styles', function() {
    return gulp.src(source.styles)
        .pipe(plumber())
        .pipe(gulpif(/\.less$/, plumber().pipe(less({
            strictMath: true,
            strictUnits: true,
        }))))
        .pipe(concat('bundle.css'))
        .pipe(prefixer(['last 2 versions', '> 1%', 'ie 9'], {cascade: false}))
        .pipe(minifyCss())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('public/css'));
});
```

Libraries used:

- [gulp-less](https://github.com/plus3network/gulp-less)
- [gulp-if](https://github.com/robrich/gulp-if)
- [gulp-concat](https://github.com/wearefractal/gulp-concat)
- [gulp-autoprefixer](https://github.com/Metrime/gulp-autoprefixer)
- [gulp-minify-css](https://github.com/jonathanepollack/gulp-minify-css)

I know [less](http://lesscss.org/usage/#command-line-usage-source-map-output-filename) can generate sourcemaps, gulp-concat I don't think supports them, [autoprefixer](https://github.com/ai/autoprefixer) is supposed to preserve them, and minify-css/[clean-css](https://github.com/GoalSmashers/clean-css) don't seem to make any mention of source maps. Am I out of luck?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've been having the same issue tonight, and I'm still working on finding out a clean solution. However, I just managed to get something working so I thought I would share:

Note: I'm using neither `gulpif` nor `minify`

Use `gulp-sourcemaps` since `gulp-less` seems to come without the source map option (at least for the moment).

<s>Replace `gulp-concat` by `gulp-concat-sourcemap` to preserve the sourcemaps.</s>

<s>Gulp-concat isn't currently supported by gulp-sourcemaps (cf. [README](https://github.com/floridoo/gulp-sourcemaps#usage)). 
Until that gets fixed there's a patched version to grab here: https://github.com/floridoo/gulp-concat/tree/sourcemap_pipe2</s>

```
gulp.task('less', function () {
  gulp.src(sources.less)
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(less())
    .pipe(prefix({ map: true })) 
    .pipe(concat('build.css'))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write()
    .pipe(gulp.dest(dirs.build + 'assets/css'));
});
```

Comment: Almost there; are you doing any kind of minification?

Comment: Not yet, doing this for dev env only ftm. Any hints please let me/us know !

Comment: Good point, maybe I should drop the minification step on dev too. I'm not sure I need sourcemaps in production anyway.

Comment: That would be a waste indeed, but as a proof of concept it would be nice to see it working :-) ... I noticed all the line numbers in my source maps were offset by about 7 lines. Not sure where that's coming from. Again not a big deal but just makes it all feel a bit unstable.

Comment: My line numbers are even more off than that. Paths are all screwy too, can't seem to get them right.

Comment: Looks all perfectly neat on my side (for now). I've edited the answer so check the diff.

Comment: tx, looks like gulp-concat is supported now…

Comment: Thanks @memeLab for letting us know, I've updated the answer.

Comment: Please edit it to say you are using "gulp-sourcemapS" instead of "gulp-sourcemap." Caused me a major headache!

Answer (score 3):

Since version 2 of Less you can use plugins for the Less compiler. Also gulp-less allows you to use these plugins (programmatic) see also http://lesscss.org/usage/#plugins-using-a-plugin-in-code

Documentation of gulp-less describes how to use the clean-css and autoprefix plugin at https://github.com/plus3network/gulp-less#plugins. Notice that gulp-minify-css is leveraging clean-css's code too.

Also the usage of gulp-less with gulp-sourcemaps to create sourcemaps has been described at https://github.com/plus3network/gulp-less#source-maps

So you should be able to use:

```
var LessPluginCleanCSS = require("less-plugin-clean-css"),
    cleancss = new LessPluginCleanCSS({advanced: true});

var LessPluginAutoPrefix = require('less-plugin-autoprefix'),
    autoprefix= new LessPluginAutoPrefix({browsers: ["last 2 versions"]});


gulp.src('./less/**/*.less')
  .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
  .pipe(less({
    plugins: [autoprefix, cleancss]
   }))
  .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./maps'))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/css'));
```

The above should generate the autoprefixed and minified CSS of your Less source, with CSS sourcemaps written into ./public/css/maps

Alternatively you could consider to use the [Pleeease plugin](https://github.com/bassjobsen/less-plugin-pleeease) Pleeease can run many postprocessors once, see http://pleeease.io/docs/#features

Comment: I've found when loading the CSS into chrome, that the maps files don't point to the correct lines of code?

Comment: by default your Less code had been include in the sourcemap, see also https://github.com/floridoo/gulp-sourcemaps#write-options for the `includeContent` and  `sourceRoot` options